# ARKit Showing broken UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, arkit

I'm trying to detect an image using ARImageTrackingConfiguration and when the image is detected, an UIWebView shows up instead of the image scanned. I read a lot of problems regarding the new WBWebView but is not working either.

The problem it seems that is the UIWebView is not being updated from the main thread even thought I'm using the DispatchMain.

On a related topic (the code I use is pretty much the same), if I try to put a SKVideoNode instead of a UIWebView, the video gets played super laggy with some big pixels on top if I set                 plane.cornerRadius = 0.25

The code is the following

```swift
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

        updateQueue.async {
            let physicalWidth = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
            let physicalHeight = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

            // Create a plane geometry to visualize the initial position of the detected image
            let mainPlane = SCNPlane(width: physicalWidth, height: physicalHeight)

            mainPlane.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = .alpha

            // Create a SceneKit root node with the plane geometry to attach to the scene graph
            // This node will hold the virtual UI in place
            let mainNode = SCNNode(geometry: mainPlane)
            mainNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            mainNode.renderingOrder = -1
            mainNode.opacity = 1

            // Add the plane visualization to the scene
            node.addChildNode(mainNode)

            // Perform a quick animation to visualize the plane on which the image was detected.
            // We want to let our users know that the app is responding to the tracked image.
            self.highlightDetection(on: mainNode, width: physicalWidth, height: physicalHeight, completionHandler: {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/")!)
            let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 672))
            webView.loadRequest(request)

            let webViewPlane = SCNPlane(width: xOffset, height: xOffset * 1.4)
            webViewPlane.cornerRadius = 0.25

            let webViewNode = SCNNode(geometry: webViewPlane)
            webViewNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = webView
            webViewNode.position.z -= 0.5
            webViewNode.opacity = 0

            rootNode.addChildNode(webViewNode)
            webViewNode.runAction(.sequence([
                .wait(duration: 3.0),
                .fadeOpacity(to: 1.0, duration: 1.5),
                .moveBy(x: xOffset * 1.1, y: 0, z: -0.05, duration: 1.5),
                .moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.05, duration: 0.2)
                ])
            )
        }


            })
        }
    }


VIDEO VERSION

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

        updateQueue.async {
            let physicalWidth = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
            let physicalHeight = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

            // Create a plane geometry to visualize the initial position of the detected image
            let mainPlane = SCNPlane(width: physicalWidth, height: physicalHeight)

            mainPlane.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = .alpha

            // Create a SceneKit root node with the plane geometry to attach to the scene graph
            // This node will hold the virtual UI in place
            let mainNode = SCNNode(geometry: mainPlane)
            mainNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            mainNode.renderingOrder = -1
            mainNode.opacity = 1

            // Add the plane visualization to the scene
            node.addChildNode(mainNode)

            // Perform a quick animation to visualize the plane on which the image was detected.
            // We want to let our users know that the app is responding to the tracked image.
            self.highlightDetection(on: mainNode, width: physicalWidth, height: physicalHeight, completionHandler: {

                let size = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize

                var videoNode = SKVideoNode()

                switch imageAnchor.name {
                case "Elephant-PostCard":
                    videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "Movies/cat.mp4")

                case "puppy":
                    videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "puppy.mov")
                default:
                    break
                }
                // invert our video so it does not look upside down
                videoNode.yScale = -1.0

                videoNode.play()

                let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720))

                videoScene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
                videoScene.addChild(videoNode)

                let plane = SCNPlane(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                plane.cornerRadius = 0.25
                plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene

                let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
                plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

                mainNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: avoid using `UIWebView`. It is deprecated. use `WKWebView`

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the post I already tried with WKWebView butt I just doesn't work... And from what I found in stackoverflow.com many users reported that with ARKit, WKWebView doesn't work and it's best to use Uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

[UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) from `UIKit` module is now deprecated.

Use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) from `WebKit` module instead.